# How much should I avoid making internal communication?

Tags: database

I'm trying to figure out the best practice for querying databases or other services.

If I can make one large query to a database once and sort the data in the backend should I do that over making many small queries and let (for example) an SQL database to do filtering for me.

**Example**

[image: Database diagram]

Lets say `DeviceData` carries lots of data time points for the devices in `Device`.
If I need seperate arrays for all the datapoints for each device in `Device` is it better practice to:

1. Query `Device` for a list of devices then query `DeviceData` induvidually for each device
2. Query `DeviceData` for all the data then sort the data into seperate arrays for each device in the backend

Comment: How many devices and how many data time points per device do you have? 10s, 100s, 1000s, millions? How many client apps access the back-end at once? How often is the data updated? Do all devices need fetching at once, or do you only ever show a subset to the user? Do all data time points for one device need fetching at once? Are there memory constraints, time constraints, cost constraints etc on your system? Does the solution need to scale to orders of magnitude more data? Over what time frame? All these questions and more influence the correct choice of solution for your specific case.

Comment: So one thing is for sure, "*it is absolutely the correct choice to make one big query to get all data*" from the answer you have accepted is a naïve and simplistic assumption based on very little evidence. You may regret the decision to follow that advice (or you may not: there's too little info to know either way).

Comment: Isn't this just "do a join"?

Comment: @DavidArno there is nothing naive or simplistic about answering the question as it's asked when it represents a very common and typical case. I have explictly said that it's the correct choice in *most* cases and mentioned that it doesn't apply for large amounts of data. Unless you just want to be needlessly contrarian by coming up with exotic scenarios, the basic concept that required data should be fetched with as few queries as possible holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each query to the database carries a significant overhead (especially network communication) that is typically *thousands of times* bigger than in-memory processing.

In most cases, including your example, it is absolutely the correct choice to make one big query to get all data and then sort it on the receiving end (into objects or collections, of course use SORT BY on the DB where appropriate). In fact, the alternative option is a performance bug that is so common that it has its own name: the [N+1 query problem](https://medium.com/doctolib/understanding-and-fixing-n-1-query-30623109fe89).

The only cases where it would be better to make many small queries is if the total amount of data is too large to fit into memory, but even then you want to keep the number of queries as low as possible (i.e. get the data in batches, not each piece individually).

Comment: There is another case, and that's where pessimistic locking would cause the large query to block access to the database to other users for prolonged periods of time.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't get behind this answer. You should select, group & sort on the DB.  You will never do a better job.  The N+1 problem can occur but it's not guaranteed.  I'd select & sort then read the stream breaking when the device ID changes.  The need for a huge memory footprint is irrelevant and depends on your need to have all devices available in memory. That's an algorithm or application problem.

Comment: @LoztInSpace: You're actually agreeing with me, but apparently misunderstanding OP's question. "select & sort then read the stream breaking when the device ID changes" still means one query. OP asks if they should do individual queries for each device.

Comment: if by 'then sort it on the receiving end' you actually mean 'then process it in groups on the receiving end' then I agree. Sorting on the client, no.

Comment: @LoztInSpace: yes, we're in agreement :)

Comment: @LoztInSpace: On board with your comment, but there are some exceptions here, when the filtering logic is not something that the db provider can elegantly handle (e.g. deserializing a JSON string to filter on one of its values). It's an edge case, but a relevant exception to an otherwise "never".

Comment: @Flater - that's an indicator of a different kind of design problem.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a single query causes fewer network overhead, unless the resulting data is massive, far more than you'd send if there were multiple smaller queries.

If that's the case however, it may well be beneficial to create a stored procedure and do all the work on the server, returning only the result of the filters you'd otherwise apply clientside to the client.

And yes, I know stored procedures are pretty much the boogeyman of younger programmers who think the database should only be a stupid datadump :)

In your case, I'd probably cache the content of Device on the client, refreshing the content of that cache at regular intervals (interval length depending on how frequently changes to the table are expected and how critical it is to always have the latest information), then use that cached data to get the keys into the DeviceData table to extract the information you're actually looking for.

That way you reduce both the number of queries to the database and the amount of superfluous data being sent by a large query that'd extract everything in one big gulp.

But generally there is no ones size fits all scenario for things like this, you have to weigh the benefits of different solutions and choose the one most optimal for your situation.

Answer (score 1):

As with most things, you need to strike a balance here. Too many queries is a problem because of the overhead of the network. Too big of a query is a problem due to sheer bandwidth usage, including (but not limited to) the likelihood that you might not need all the data you're fetching.

You also have to consider how you intend to process this data.

> If I can make one large query to a database once and **sort** the data in the backend

Sorting can be done by the database and does not impact query size. The database server is usually the best component to do the sorting as db providers specialize in these kinds of optimizations.

However, I suspect that you are using "sort" not to mean "putting things in order" (which is the correct definition), you are using it to mean "making individual subgroups" (which in database terminology is called "grouping").

More on grouping later in this answer.

> and let (for example) an SQL database to do **filtering** for me.

Filtering is a different ballgame.

If you don't let the database do the filtering, that means that you will be fetching to-be-filtered data over your network connection, which is a waste of bandwidth since you (by definition) have no use for this data.
To take the extreme cases, if you expect to retain 90% of the fetched data after filtering, that's not a huge problem. If you expect to retain 10% of the fetched data after filtering, that means you sent ten times more data than you actually needed, and that's really not good.

That being said, if your filtering logic is sufficiently complex in a way that: your query language cannot optimize it, you're using non-indexed data, you have to parse some data (e.g. JSON string) before applying your filtering logic,... this is where it becomes more reasonable to offload the filtering duties to your runtime instead of your database, because the database might actually do a worse job than your runtime will, and if you have the bandwidth to spare, it might be a better choice.

However, the point remains that for all basic query operations, the database provider is inherently built to provide these services, and it is generally going to outperform your logic because it pre-emptively builds indexes and optimizes queries. The example you give here is a basic query operation, it is not a fringe case where the database can't reasonably handle it.

Therefore, if you *can* let the database do the work with reasonable performance, you should let it do so.

> Lets say `DeviceData` carries lots of data time points for the devices in `Device`. If I need seperate arrays for all the datapoints for each device in Device is it better practice to:
>
> 1. Query `Device` for a list of devices then query `DeviceData` induvidually for each device
> 2. Query `DeviceData` for all the data then sort the data into seperate arrays for each device in the backend

**Short answer**

The expectation here is that you don't filter away any data and that you will need all of the loaded `DeviceData` records. In this case, you can just perform one big query.

*Caveat: I assume your runtime has the memory to spare to load all of this data. Otherwise, your question is moot to begin with as loading everything in a single go would be impossible anyway.*

I suggest you have the database sort the records by device ID first, to simplify the grouping logic you will perform afterwards.

**Long answer**

However, you've not listed any specific tech stack you're working with. Depending on what technologies you're working with, this problems can be significantly simplified from your end.
I'm going to use the example of SQL server and Entity Framework, because it's the one I'm most familiar with, but be aware that alternatives with similar features do exist.

Your assumption is that you must individually query the database for each device if you want this data to be grouped accordingly. This is not correct. SQL's [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) allows you to group your data based on a given value. If you group by device ID, you get exactly what you are looking for.

By itself, GROUP BY cannot be used to fetch all the records from all the groups, since a single query still only yields a single collection. However, ORMs like Entity Framework are able to leverage GROUP BY and allow you to fetch all the needed data *and* have it grouped the way you want it to be, all done via the database provider, which is the more performant solution. This is the best of both worlds for your case.

An EF example would be (I assume device ID is an int):

```
Dictionary <int, List<DeviceData> deviceDataPerDeviceId =
    context
        .DeviceData
        .GroupBy(dd => dd.DeviceId)
        .ToDictionary(
            group => group.Key,       // dictionary key = group ID (= device ID)
            group => group.ToList()   // dictionary value = the group's records
         );
```

This is just a basic example, things can be tweaked the way you need them to be. ORMs have many of these features that help you intelligently query your data source. If you configure EF with navigational properties, you can even do:

```
List<Device> devices =
    context
        .Devices
        .Include(d => d.DeviceData)
        .ToList();
```

which fetches both the `Device` entities *and* their individual `DeviceData` collections.

These are just some basic example of how you can leverage an ORM to significantly simplify how you query your database.